# How to avoid flickering on box shadow transition?

Tags: html, css

I have CSS that **animates** box shadow ***on hover***. It works on Firefox but causes flickering in **Opera/Chrome** **browser**.

Is it possible to fix it without extra markup and without pseudo elements?

```css
.hover {
    color: #fff;
    background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;    
    transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;
}
.hover:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 424px 0 0 0 #fff;
   color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hover">This is some really looong title!</h1>
```

Comment: Flickering also happens in Chrome for me.

Comment: Yup looks like it does on Chrome too;(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try setting a boxshadow of .09px

```css
.hover {
max-width: 400px;
    color: red;
    background-color:  blue;
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.09px white;    
    transition: all ease 5.5s;
}
.hover:hover {
    background-color:  blue;
   box-shadow: inset 440px 0 0 0 #fff;
   color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hover">This&nbsp;is&nbsp;some&nbsp;really&nbsp;looong&nbsp;title!</h1>
```

```css
.hover {
    color: #fff;
    background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.09px #fff;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;    
    transition: box-shadow linear 0.5s,color linear 0.5s;
}
.hover:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 424px 0 0 0.09px #fff;
   color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hover">This is some really looong title!</h1>
```

Comment: it works with table, inline block, whatever,  its not correct that it has to be block, thats wrong  you just need a box-shadow and 0px is not a shadow, so you have a GPU bug

Comment: FWIW - I had to set this to 0.1px, but then the flicker was gone (Chrome 81, 2.5yrs after OP).

Comment: Worked for me after setting 0.09px for box-shadow. Thanks a lot @Zuriel

Comment: Mind sharing why this works after setting the the spread value for box shadow?

Comment: @name_masked I think that it would be similar to turning off the lights (on | off) vs dimming the lights so low that its perceived as off... even though its on.  so (0.09 | 1) .   Why does this work? probably a browser rendering bug or maybe it's by design?

Comment: Strange, but many thanks for the solution. I tried it with 0.01px and it works