# How to get rid of a flicker by hovering over a button?

Tags: html, css

I have a flicker at the end of the hovering over a button

```css
.button {
    color: #add8e6;
    border: 2px solid rgb(237, 125, 194);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 18px 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(237, 125, 194);
    -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  }
  
  .slide_right:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 400px 0 0 0 rgb(237, 125, 194);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fashion Closet</title>
        <link href="/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="header_title">Fashion Closet</h1>
                <h2 class="header_subtitle">Unique look for daily routine</h22>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="actions__container">
                    <input id="search-text" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Filter looks">
                    <select id="filter-by" class="dropdown">
                        <option value="byEdited">Sort by last edited</option>
                        <option value="byCreated">Sort by recently created</option>
                        <option value="alphabetical">Sort alphabetically</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="looks"></div>
            <button id="create-look" class="button slide_right">Create a new look</button>
        </div>
        <script src="/scripts/index-bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If adding **-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;** to a **.button**, this gets underlined, and it doesn't help. What else can I try?

Maybe a problem is that I have an image as a background?

Comment: Could you upload your HTML also with a placeholder image, so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: sure, uploaded it above

Comment: What is the browser you are using? I can't see any flickering on Firefox. There is also one script you are using `index-bundle.js`, is it your own script of from a vendor? If you're using a script from a vendor please include the CDN.

Comment: hey, bundle.js is generated through webpack. I am using Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a weird bug but it seems to fix if you set your `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.01px`. Check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960449/how-to-avoid-flickering-on-box-shadow-transition).

I hope this is what you are looking for!

```css
.button {
    color: #add8e6;
    border: 2px solid rgb(237, 125, 194);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 18px 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    transition: ease-out 0.4s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.01px rgb(237, 125, 194);
  }
  
  .slide_right:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 400px 0 0 0.01px rgb(237, 125, 194);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fashion Closet</title>
        <link href="/styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="header_title">Fashion Closet</h1>
                <h2 class="header_subtitle">Unique look for daily routine</h22>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="actions__container">
                    <input id="search-text" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Filter looks">
                    <select id="filter-by" class="dropdown">
                        <option value="byEdited">Sort by last edited</option>
                        <option value="byCreated">Sort by recently created</option>
                        <option value="alphabetical">Sort alphabetically</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="looks"></div>
            <button id="create-look" class="button slide_right">Create a new look</button>
        </div>
        <script src="/scripts/index-bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, the transition just didn't work at all, so it didn't really solve my problem!

Comment: @yavnelf I checked it on Chrome and it worked fine. Can you upload it to codepen.io to check it out?